# Displaying tables like Excel

Tags: jquery, html, excel, jsp

I'm working on a web app using servlet and JSP. I have two tables and I want to display them in my page like in Excel.
For example when a click on "Table 1", like in Excel sheets, The table 1 will be displayed and the same for table 2.
Does somebody know how can I do it ? It may be done with Jquery, but I don't know how.

Comment: There are lots of ways to implement tabs in a page. Should be easy to research this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this using Bootstrap's tabs or pills, with them you can create menu options for your page with different styles (nav-tabs look like Excel tabs). Here's an example of how it works, you would only need to reference the elements to the corresponding tables and you should get the Excel look you want.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active"><a href="#">Table 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Table 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

Here's the documentation and more examples: http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_tabs_pills.asp